# почему аннотация @GetMapping не отрабатывает?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Есть контроллер

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("login")
    public String login(){
        return "/login";
    }
}
```

И в директории src/main/resources/templates два файла: index.html, login.html.
Когда запускаю приложение и перехожу по замапленным урлам, то вижу ексепции:
при /login

```
Circular view path [/login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

а при стартовой странице просто error 404.
Вот пример стартовой страницы /login:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title>Ght</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="@{/login}">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Не понимаю, почему настолько тривиальная вещь не отрабатывает(гугл рассказал про аннотацию @EnableMvc, но не помогло)
на всякий случай файл pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ru.myspringproject</groupId>
<artifactId>telegraph</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>telegraph</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

в гугле также нашел, что такое поведение может быть из-за зависимостей.

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, что проблема в пом файле. я явно указал версию драйвера mysql(и почему-то помник ругался, возможно, потому что версия автоматически подбирается под spring-boot-starter-parent), поэтому не применил на проекте зависимость таймлифа, отсюда и ошибка

Answer (score 1):

этот код нужно менять

```
       @GetMapping("login")
    public String login(){
        return "/login";
    }
}
```

вам нужно перед login-а поставить value и добавить / и в конце если вы сделаете return в jsp или thymeleaf нужно убрать этот / этот код будет выглядит вот так

```
      @GetMapping(value="/login")
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }
}
```

а что остается на jsp или thymeleaf  этот код в jsp будет выглядит вот так

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title>Ght</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="@{/login}">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

> jsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title>Ght</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/login">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

если thymeleaf

> thymeleaf

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title>Ght</title>
</head>
<body>
<a th:href="@{/login}">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```